# On possible generalizations of the Steiner ellipse – convex regions containing and contained within a given convex quadrilateral

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry

In the post [On convex regions containing (and contained within) a given triangle](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/345681/on-convex-regions-containing-and-contained-within-a-given-triangle) , it was noted:

- for a general triangle $T$, the convex region $C_M$ of largest area containing $T$ such that $T$ is  the largest area triangle that is contained within $C_M$ is the Steiner circumellipse of $T$.

**New Questions** (generalizing from triangle):

1. Given a general convex quadrilateral $Q$, which is the convex region $C_M$ of largest area containing $Q$ such that $Q$  is also the largest area convex quadrilateral contained within $C_M$? Is it a $3$-ellipse? If so, does this generalize to convex $n$-gons and $(n-1)$-ellipses?
2. What about the convex region $C_m$ of least area contained in $Q$ such that $Q$ is also the smallest area quadrilateral containing $C_m$? Is it too a $3$-ellipse?

Note: I do not know the answers to questions that can be generated with perimeter replacing area in any of the above questions including those asked in [On convex regions containing (and contained within) a given triangle](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/345681/on-convex-regions-containing-and-contained-within-a-given-triangle).

Related discussions:
[On Convex Regions Contained in Convex Polygons](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/393174/on-convex-regions-contained-in-convex-polygons),
[On convex polygons contained in convex polygons](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/389865/on-convex-polygons-contained-in-convex-polygons), [Smallest 3-ellipses that contain triangles](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/403370/smallest-3-ellipses-that-contain-triangles)